# PHP: populate MySQL table with result of anagram creation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to populate a MySQL table with the result of a function to create anagrams from a given word. There is simply no result at all. I even do not get an error message.

```
 <?php

//connect to your database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","3423423sfdfsdf","mydb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $input = $trimmed;

function string_getpermutations($prefix, $characters, &$permutations)
{
    if (count($characters) == 1)
        $permutations[] = $prefix . array_pop($characters);
    else
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($characters); $i++)
        {
            $tmp = $characters;
            unset($tmp[$i]);

            string_getpermutations($prefix . $characters[$i], array_values($tmp), $permutations);
        }
    }
}
$characters = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
    $characters[] = $input[$i];

$permutations = array();

string_getpermutations("", $characters, $permutations);

foreach($permutations  as $result) {echo $result,'<br>';}

foreach($permutations  as $result) {mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tempanagram (anagram) VALUES ('$result')");}

    ?>
```

Comment: Code snippets are only for html/js/css questions.  Unfortunately the scaffolding required to run PHP "server-side" and render the results is understandably not implemented on stack overflow.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're in a constant loop since the function keeps calling itself without a terminator. It calls itself 40 times with a 4 character string (test), 8659 with a 7 character string (testing)

Comment: That was another problem. How do I avoid the loop? I actually would like to have only distinct results.

Comment: You can't avoid loops, but you can use 1 insert query like: `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (set1), (set2), (setN)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mysqli`, but best solution is using some query builders.

Add to your code error reporting for PHP and MYSQL

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true)
mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die('ERROR: '.mysqli_error($conn));
```

More info in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

You can optimize your code to make 1 insert query by using bulk insert, something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tempanagram (anagram) VALUES ("'.join('"),("', $permutations).'")';
```

Comment: The connection is as follows:
`@$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','theuser','thepassword') or die("Error connecting to database");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//specify database
mysql_select_db("thedatabase",$conn);`

Comment: 1. change `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`; 2. what about error handling?

Comment: O.k. connection changed to mysqli_*. I also noticed that I cannot used special characters in the password because it must be stored somewhere where I have no influence with wrong character settings. Populating the table still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

Instead of `foreach($permutations  as $result) {mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tempanagram (anagram) VALUES ('$result')");}`

I had to write:

```
foreach($permutations  as $result) {mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tempanagram (anagram) VALUES ('$result')");}
```

Otherwise it is apparently not clear that I am referring to that connection.

All the other hints are very valuable. Thanks very much to everybody.